# Baby version of Sturm Comparison Theorem

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

In Problem 15-32 of Spivak's *Calculus*, 4th edition, he proves the following:

> Suppose $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ satisfy  $$\phi_1''+g_1\phi_1=0, \\
>  \phi_2''+g_2\phi_2 = 0,\\[10pt] g_2>g_1, \\[10pt] \phi_1(a)=\phi_1(b)
>  = 0,\\ \phi_1\neq0 \text{ on } (a,b).$$
>
> Then $\phi_2$ has a zero in $(a,b)$.

He then says,

> As a particular example, any solution of the differential equation
>   $$y''+(x+1)y=0$$ must have at least one zero in any interval $(n\pi
>  ,(n+1)\pi)$.

I gather he's talking about comparing to cosine or sine, where $g_1$ would be the constant function $1$. My question is: it seems that the example he gives only follows from the problem if $n$ is greater than zero (and by a short argument we could include $n=0$). Otherwise we do not have $g_2>g_1 = 1$ and we can't compare to sine or cosine.  Am I correct about this, or am I thinking about it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric: You are correct that one needs $n\ge 0$ for the proof to work. Indeed, as this plot suggests, there are no zeroes on $x<0$.

[image]